# Can't run artisan redis:subscribe command as service, in background and daemon

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-artisan, supervisord

I'm trying to run `redis:subscribe` artisan command as a service, in background mode and need that script not to die on error.

I have tried Supervisor, but no result.

Do you have any suggestions?

---

- OS: CentOS 7
- Lang: PHP
- Framework: Laravel

Comment: What are the issues your having with supervisor? This is pretty much the go to for what your trying tod .

Comment: So, when I'm checking for program status, supervisor is saying that it's running. But, when I'm trying to publish something from node server to Laravel's redis, I have no output.

When I call `php artisan redis:subscribe` manually, then it's working, and I'm getting the output in **laravel.log**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found best solution for this.

I've made `bash` file, that is running my script. It's checking for error and restarting script execution. And I've put this `bash` file in startup, to run as server.

This is my whole magic:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

nohup path/to/php /path/to/artisan redis:subscribe >> /path/to/logs/redis.log &

PID=$!
wait $PID
echo $PID has ended

sleep 1;
done;
```

I hope someone will find it helpful.

Comment: And you need to change 'default_socket_connection'. By default it is 60 seconds and if connection is not used for 60 seconds, it will be interrupted

Answer (score 1):

Trying to execute this command :

```
php artisan redis:subscribe &
```

The '&' allow to set cmd as deamon.

Comment: I was searching information about `&`  at the end of command. As I realized it only runs the command in background. If script fails, it wouldn't be restarted. But I need this command to keep running regardless of errors.